# Can I make content that was hidden appear when moved to div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that moves all of the objects in a class to a div. There are some radio buttons that I've set to display:none but I want them to be visible when moved to the div. The code below worked with paragraphs, but not with radio buttons/labels. Any way to do this? Thanks!

```js
var cCount = 0;

function changeDiv() {
  alert("tochange" + cCount);
  var changeClass = document.getElementsByClassName("Q" + cCount);
  var changeDiv = document.getElementById("question");
  for (var i = 0; i < changeClass.length; i++) {
    changeDiv.innerHTML = changeDiv.innerHTML + changeClass[i];
  }
  cCount++;
}
```

```css
.Q0 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="question">
  <form>
    <p id="cap" class="Q0"> question 1?</p><br />
    <input type="radio" ID="opt1" name="home" class="Q0" /><label class="Q0">value1</label><br />
    <input type="radio" ID="opt2" name="home" class="Q0" /><label class="Q0">value2</label><br />
  </form>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="changeDiv()" /><label>bnt</label>
```

Comment: You probably want `changeClass[i].outerHTML`. Depending on how you set them to `display:none`, you may have to show them again after the move.

Comment: Still doesn't work, I set the display using CSS if that helps?

Comment: Can you inspect the receiving `div` and see if the elements are where you're expecting them? Note that right now, your code won't do much except move the elements out of the `form`, since they are already descendants of `question`. Also, please [edit] your question and include the CSS you're using to hide them.

Comment: I moved the form out of the div. The div successfully receives the paragraph element but not the radio buttons so I'm pretty sure it's coming from the right place?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish with this code, since as I mentioned, you're moving the elements to the same place as they are already. I've taken the liberty of updating your question to use Stack Snippets so you can see the results of the code in the question.

Comment: I changed the code so that the form is not in the div, that was my original intention and I didn't notice the mistake at first. I have more classes names Q1,Q2,etc. and I'd like to display the contents of the next class in order when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd put the `Q0` class on a single parent div to make its children easier to move, then move that `Q0` div to the `question` div.

As for the CSS, you can hide the questions until the button is clicked by using `position: absolute` and `visibility: hidden;` on the `form` tag.

```js
var cCount = 0;

function nextQuestion() {
  var lastQuestionDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("Q" + (cCount - 1))[0];
  var nextQuestionDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("Q" + cCount)[0];
  var questionDiv = document.getElementById("question");
  // Remove last question. Optionally, can do "if (cCount > 0)"
  if (lastQuestionDiv) questionDiv.removeChild(lastQuestionDiv);
  if (nextQuestionDiv) {
    questionDiv.appendChild(nextQuestionDiv);
    cCount++;
  } else {
    // No more questions
  }
}
```

```css
form {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="question">
  <form>
    <div class="Q0">
      <p id="cap"> question 1?</p><br />
      <input type="radio" ID="q1opt1" name="home" /><label>value1</label><br />
      <input type="radio" ID="q1opt2" name="home" /><label>value2</label><br />
    </div>
    <div class="Q1">
      <p id="cap"> question 2?</p><br />
      <input type="radio" ID="q2opt1" name="home" /><label>value1</label><br />
      <input type="radio" ID="q2opt2" name="home" /><label>value2</label><br />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<button id="btn" onclick="nextQuestion()">Next Question</button>
```

Comment: If I have another class that I want to take the place of Q0 when the button is pressed a second time is there a way to do that? Your answer works (thank you) but just adds on questions

Comment: See my updated answer. Hopefully you don't mind that I renamed the variables to make it easier to read.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the if statement is checking.

Comment: It's checking if the div exists. On the first click it will be trying to remove a div with the class `Q-1` from the question div, which doesn't exist. Optionally, it could be written as `if (cCount > 0)`.